# ImageViews populated by URL in CustomArrayAdapter Asynchronously

Tags: android

Hi i have an arrayList of urls that i want to pass into a customArrayAdapter that displays the images in a list. I also want this to be performed asynchronously. so far i have tried creating a drawable from the URL inside the CustomArrayAdapter and putting that function within an ASyncTask but i'm struggling to get it working is this the best method of doing this or does anyone know of a better way?

heres what i have tried so far

```
ImageView contactImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.docicon);


            if(imageURLs != null){

                ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
                imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(getContext()));
                imageLoader.displayImage(image, contactImage);

            }else{

            contactImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sc_user); 
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For asynchronously loading images into `ImageViews` from a network resource, I highly recommend using one of the following libraries:

- [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) - My favorite, highly customizable
- [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)
- [Volley](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley)

For example, loading an `ImageView` from a network resource using UniversalImageLoader is as simple as...

```
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView);
```

Comment: tanks for the help i have edited my code above with an implementation of the Universal image loader inside a getView in a custom array adapter however its not displaying my images do you know why?

Comment: Scratch that i solved it the url i was passing in wasn't complete

Comment: PS can't thank you enough for introducing me to universal image loaders its fantastic